# User journey path

Tags: r, string, text-analysis

I have a following dataset:

```
     ID   IntNo   Conv          Path
 743479       4      0      homepage
 743479       3      0         page1
 743479       2      0         page2
 743479       1      0         page3
 743479       0      1         page4
 746523       2      0      homepage
 746523       1      0         page3
 746523       0      1         page4
1225709       1      0      homepage
1225709       0      1         page4
```

I want to get the output like this:

```
Path                                 Conv
homepage>page1>page2>page3>page4        1
homepage>page3>page4                    1
homepage>page4                          1
```

For this I have used the following code:

```
users_path <-  lapply(unique(datset$ID), 
                function(x)  list( path= paste(dataset[dataset$ID==x,'Path'],  sep="", collapse=">"), 
                                   total_conversions= length( datset[dataset$ID==x,'Path']) ) )

users_path<-do.call('rbind', users_path)
users_path<-data.frame(users_path)
```

But the output I am getting is the following:

```
Path   Total_conversions
Path                   1
Path                   1
Path                   1
```

Can you help me to identify the error?

Comment: Next time please use `dput(dataframe)` for us to quickly create the dataframe.

Comment: Not like that bro. the actual dataframe. Then paste the output. Like dput(dataframeNAME) and then paste the output.

Comment: @MaxPD  In this case it is easy to use `df <- read.table(stdin(), header = TRUE)`.

Comment: Oh ok. Never used dput before. Sorry!

Comment: Downvote for no-repro code, there's a `dataset` and `datset` without any clue of what is what.

Answer (score 1):

If your data is in data.table the following will do:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- as.data.table(df)
dt[, list(Path = paste(Path, sep="", collapse=">")), by = ID][, list(Total_conversions = .N), by = Path]
```

Comment: receiving an error that "The items in the 'by' or 'keyby' list are length (24900). Each must be same length as rows in x or number of rows returned by i (7316)."

Comment: What do you obtain when run first part `dt[, list(Path = paste(Path, sep="", collapse=">")), by = ID]`?

Comment: Why not in one step as in `setDT(df)[, .(Total_conversions = sum(Conv), 
              Path = paste(Path, collapse = ">")), 
         by = ID]`?

Answer (score -2):

Sorry all,

The code was right. I had read the table as data.table.

```
 dataset<-data.frame(dataset)
```

After converting it into a dataframe, my function worked fine.

```
users_path <-  lapply(unique(datset$ID), 
            function(x)  list( path= paste(dataset[dataset$ID==x,'Path'],  sep="", collapse=">"), 
                               total_conversions= length( datset[dataset$ID==x,'Path']) ) )
users_path<-do.call('rbind', users_path)
```

Thnks for the help

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a forum, please take time to read the [tour] and [answer].

Comment: If this code is working, you didn't tell what is `datset` ... 1) there's a typo, 2) your env is unclean and you get unexpected results, 3) Combination of the two preceding.